# AWS Athena query on parquet file - using columns in where clause

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, parquet, amazon-athena

We are planning to use Athena as a backend service for our data(stored as parquet files in partitions) in S3.

Some of the things we are interested to find out is how does adding additional columns in where clause of the query affect the query run time.
For example, we have 10million records in one hive partition(partition based on column 'date')

And all queries below return same volume - 10million. would all these queries take same time or does it reduce query run when we add additional columns in where clause(as parquet is columnar fomar)?
I tried to test this but results were not consistent as there was some queuing time as well I guess

1. `select * from table where date='20200712'`
2. `select * from table where date='20200712' and type='XXX'`
3. `select * from table where date='20200712' and type='XXX' and subtype='YYY'`

Comment: What do you mean by "all queries below return same volume – 10 million"? It sounds like you are saying that all three queries would return all rows in the partition, in which case I don't understand what the `type` and `subtype` filters would be for? I assume that I'm misunderstanding you here, could you clarify?

Comment: not all time filters can reduce the count right? Assuming I dont know when querying, that all of the records with date 20200712 have type as XXX and subtype as YYY. I am interested in finding if additional filters have any effect if they dont reduce the number of records reduced..for a hive query on parquet file as parquet is column based format

Answer (score 1):

Parquet file contains page "indexes" (min, max and bloom filters.)  If you sorting the data by columns in question during insert for example like this:

```
insert overwrite table mytable partition (dt)
select col1, --some columns
       type, 
       subtype, 
       dt
 distribute by dt
       sort by type, subtype
```

then these indexes may work efficiently because data withe the same type, subtype will be loaded into the same pages, data pages will be selected using indexes. See some benchmarks here: https://blog.cloudera.com/speeding-up-select-queries-with-parquet-page-indexes/

Switch-on predicate-push-down: https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/cdh_ig_predicate_pushdown_parquet.html

Comment: thank you..the way we have generated parquet is using pandas from an existing csv file..so dont have control on insert?

Comment: my question is basically how adding additional columns in where clause affect hive query performence, though total records returned is same with or without additional columns when files are in parquet format

Comment: @NareshK If the data is not sorted and you are selecting all columns, you will not notice any difference.

Comment: there are different ways to generate parquet..using spark on AWS EMR, or AWS glue job or pandas..which one is the best..does parquet need to have partition within the parquet file to give better performence?

Comment: @NareshK Please ask another question, not in the comment, someone else may help